# Ruby - Matching a value and returning a corresponding value from a separate file

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to match one value (A sku from a website) to the same value (A sku from lookup.csv) and return a corresponding model (From lookup.csv).

Here's sample data from lookup.csv:

SKU , Model

2520045 , DQ.SUNAA.002

7423599 , DA.MX00.1CC

9547543 , DX.MF01.2BM

Here's my code thus far:

```
url = "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/acer-aspire-23-touch-screen-all-in-one-intel-core-i5-8gb-memory-2tb-hard-drive-black/2520045.p?id=1219547718151&skuId=2520045"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

sku = page.css('span#sku-value').text

#model = match the sku to the sku in lookup.csv and return corresponding model

puts model
```

I know that I can open the file with

```
open("lookup.csv", 'r')
```

but past that, I'm not quite sure how to match/return a corresponding value.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of Aoukar would work but be slow with large data sets.
Here a better solution, read the CSV once, using the [CSV gem](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) (no need to reinvent the wheel) and store the data in a hash, after that you can just ask fort the right Model, here a working sample.
I'm using the CSV data in the DATA part of the script here so I don't need the CSV file itself.

```
require "csv"

lookup = {}
CSV.parse(DATA, col_sep: " , ", headers: true, force_quotes: false, :quote_char => "\x00").each do |row|
  lookup.merge! Hash[row['SKU'], row['Model']]
end

lookup #{"2520045"=>"DQ.SUNAA.002", "7423599"=>"DA.MX00.1CC", "9547543"=>"DX.MF01.2BM"}
lookup['2520045'] #"DQ.SUNAA.002"
__END__
_ ,SKU , Model #the first element is to work around a bug in CSV used this way
2520045 , DQ.SUNAA.002
7423599 , DA.MX00.1CC
9547543 , DX.MF01.2BM
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter.  I tried this and so far, when I run it, I get a blank returned.  Here's how I implemented your code:

    `sku = page.css('span#sku-value').text`

    `lookup = {}`
    `CSV.parse('lookup.csv', col_sep: ",", headers: true, force_quotes: false, :quote_char => "\x00").each do |row|`
      `lookup.merge! Hash[row['SKU'], row['Model']]`
    `end`

`puts lookup[sku]`

I will eventually need to add a third column to this csv for Manufacturer that I'll need to match a SKU to just like I did with Model.  Will this be possible using the same/similar solution you provided?

Comment: A question out of curiosity, when loading the file in a variable wouldn't that increase the memory size used by the script? so it's a trade off between speed and memory?

Comment: today's computers have memory enough and it would have to be a very large file to pose a problem, anyway with such a large file your approach would be slow as hell, i would advise reading the data into a database then

Comment: @Nick, the sample I provided runs fine so it's something you added, eg lookup[sku] is not the same as lookup[SKU], case matters and yes you will be able to use this method but instead of just a key with value you will need a key with a collection of vallus such as an Array, other Hash or a Struct, let me know if that is a problem the I provide some additional code

Comment: @peter, Thank you.  I'm gonna give that a shot soon.  My code works for now, so once I'm done writing this script, I'll likely be looking to speed it up and trim any verbose code, in which case I'll return to this solution.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, but I didn't test it so it might need some modifications, I've written it as a function since it's what I'm used to.

```
def search(path,key) #path to file, and word to search for
  File.open(path,'r') do |file| #open file
    file.readlines.each { |line| #read lines array
      if line.split(' , ')[0] == key #match the SKU
        return line.split(' , ')[1] #return the Model
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Or you could use/check out the 'csv' library

Comment: Thank you for your help Aoukar.  This is what I imagined the solution would look like; however, I'm going to look further into Peter's solution as it promises to work better with large data sets (Which is what I will eventually be working with).  I will likely try both after I get the other one to work, tho.

Comment: Just as note, this solution worked great right out of the gate.